# Python's __reduce__/copy_reg semantic and stateful unpickler

Tags: python, pickle

I want to implement pickling support for objects belonging to my extension library. There is a global instance of class Service initialized at startup. All these objects are produced as a result of some Service method invocations and essentially belong to it. Service knows how to serialize them into binary buffers and how deserialize buffers back into objects.

It appeared that Pythons __ reduce__ should serve my purpose - implement pickling support. I started implementing one and realized that there is an issue with unpickler (first element od a tuple expected to be returned by __ reduce__). This unpickle function needs instance of a Service to be able to convert input buffer into an Object. Here is a bit of pseudo code to illustrate the issue:

```
class Service(object):
   ...
   def pickleObject(self,obj):
      # do serialization here and return buffer
      ...

   def unpickleObject(self,buffer):
      # do deserialization here and return new Object
      ...

class Object(object):
    ...
    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.service().unpickleObject, (self.service().pickleObject(self),)
```

Note the first element in a tuple. Python pickler does not like it: it says it is instancemethod and it can't be pickled. Obviously pickler is trying to store the routine into the output and wants Service instance along with function name, but this is not want I want to happen. I do not want (and really can't : Service is not pickable) to store service along with all the objects. I want service instance to be created before pickle.load is invoked and somehow that instance get used during unpickling.

Here where I came by copy_reg module. Again it appeared as it should solve my problems. This module allows to register pickler and unpickler routines per type dynamically and these are supposed to be used later on for the objects of this type. So I added this registration to the Service construction:

```
class Service(object):
  ...
  def __init__(self):
      ...
      import copy_reg
      copy_reg( mymodule.Object, self.pickleObject, self.unpickleObject )
```

self.unpickleObject is now a bound method taking service as a first parameter and buffer as second. self.pickleObject is also bound method taking service and object to pickle. copy_reg required that pickleObject routine should follow reducer semantic and returns similar tuple as before. And here the problem arose again: what should I return as the first tuple element??

```
class Service(object):
  ...
  def pickleObject(self,obj):
      ...
      return self.unpickleObject, (self.serialize(obj),)
```

In this form pickle again complains that it can't pickle instancemethod. I tried None - it does not like it either. I put there some dummy function. This works - meaning serialization phase went through fine, but during unpickling it calls this dummy function instead of unpickler I registered for the type mymodule.Object in Service constructor.

So now I am at loss. Sorry for long explanation: I did not know how to ask this question in a few lines. I can summarize my questions like this:

1. Why does copy_reg semantic requires me to return unpickler routine from pickleObject, if I an expected to register one independently?
2. Is there any reason to prefer copy_reg.constructor interface to register unpickler routine?
3. How do I make pickle to use the unpickler I registered instead of one inside the stream?
4. What should I return as first element in a tuple as pickleObject result value? Is there a "correct" value?
5. Do I approach this whole thing correctly? Is there different/simpler solution?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the `copy_reg` module is unlikely to help you much here: it is primarily a way to add `__reduce__` like features to classes that don't have that method rather than offering any special abilities (e.g. if you want to pickle objects from some library that doesn't natively support it).

The callable returned by `__reduce__` needs to be locatable in the environment where the object is to be unpickled, so an instance method isn't really appropriate.  As mentioned in the [Pickle documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types):

> In the unpickling environment this object must be either a class, a callable registered as a
>   “safe constructor” (see below), or it must have an attribute
>   `__safe_for_unpickling__` with a true value.

So if you defined a function (not method) as follows:

```
def _unpickle_service_object(buffer):
    # Grab the global service object, however that is accomplished
    service = get_global_service_object()
    return service.unpickleObject(buffer)

_unpickle_service_object.__safe_for_unpickling__ = True
```

You could now use this `_unpickle_service_object` function in the return value of your `__reduce__` methods so that your objects linked to the new environment's global `Service` object when unpickled.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. Even though I called the Service instance global, this is not exactly correct. There is indeed only one instance used in production application, but nothing says that it is global. And indeed in my unit tests I keep creating new one over and over again.

I implemented a module pickle.py in my package with routine def register(svc) and global module level variable service which is being set in register. Also this routine registers pickling/unpickling functions using copy_reg. This routine is invoked from Service constructor. There are couple problems though:

Comment: 1. This only works for a single service instance. In other words we can't have 2 different services existing simultaniously and both have pickable objects
2. This global reference is source of potential memory leak. How and When I need to clean it up?

Comment: You said the service object was global in your question, which is why I assumed that in my answer (and assumed that you'd want the other unpickled objects attached to the global service object in the new environment rather than creating a new one).

Comment: If you want to pickle the service object along with everything else, specify it as an argument to your `_unpickle_service_object` routine in addition to the buffer.  You will need to make your service class picklable for this to work, but you should end up with all your other objects connected to the same new service object when unpickled (assuming they all come from a single pickle, rather than being pickled separately).

Comment: As for Q1, I thought I did answer that: `copy_reg` is only there to let you register `__reduce__` methods for classes that don't actually have them.  Therefore, the handlers you register have the same requirements as `__reduce__`.  If you control all the code, it offers no benefits over implementing `__reduce__` directly so I suggested ignoring the module.